# ConnectionFactory Rabbitmq C# Configure

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I want to configure with ConnectionFactory

```
        connectionFactory.Uri =new Uri("rabbitmq://xxx.xx.xx.xx");
        connectionFactory.UserName = "12345678io";
        connectionFactory.Password = "123456789120er";
```

and return to me this error => "Wrong scheme in AMQP URI: rabbitmq"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RabbitMQ uses the [`amqp`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html) scheme for URI, so your `ConnectionFactory.Uri` should either start with `amqp://` or depending on your client, you can just specify your host and the client will build up the full uri for you.